# Parameter not found exception (you requested for non existent parameter private key)

Tags: symfony

I am working on web API in Symfony with help of JWT concept. Everything is fine but when I add Lexik bundle in my project then error comes:

> you have requested a non existent parameter "private key path"

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In Lexik documentation, there is a configuration part. Check it [here](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration).

You have to add to your config.yml:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%'
    public_key_path:  '%jwt_public_key_path%'
    pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
    token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'
```

And to your parameters.yml:

```
jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/private.pem' # ssh private key path
jwt_public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/public.pem'  # ssh public key path
jwt_key_pass_phrase:  ''                                         # ssh key pass phrase
jwt_token_ttl:        3600
```

Comment: sir now my security.yml giving error..sir i am stuck on this jwt concept ..please help me ..

Comment: @AshwaniSharma maybe read the lexik configuration that I posted? Or edit your answer with that error and I will try to help

Comment: sir i already made the web services in symfony3 .but i want to use jwt concept that is very secure ..so i am requesting you please send your email id ..so that i can send u my code ..

Comment: Add your private password in paremeter.yml.

jwt_key_pass_phrase: "yourpassword"

It will work.